# Do I need UK transit visa for the itinerary Sydney > London Heathrow > Dublin?

Tags: uk, transit-visas, indonesian-citizens

Although I'm sure a lot of you tired of seeing this question, but I'm never really get the answer that suits my situation.

I will fly with Qantas from Dublin to Sydney. My Qantas flight back to Europe will end at London Heathrow, and I will transfer at LHR to British Air for the last leg to Dublin (11th July QF1 to BA828).

Full itinerary detail (all time is local time):

1.QF1 Sydney (10/06 15:55) (stop at Changi Singapore approx 100min) to London (11/06 06:25)
2.BA828 London (11/06 08:25) to Dublin (11/06 09:50)

I am not sure whether I will passing UK immigration and custom or not, since Qantas told me I need to re-check my baggage, even though I do all the booking in one booking refernece (all of them under the same booking reference and I can see the British Airways flight in my "Manage Booking" Qantas website).

I have Indonesian passport and Irish Residence Permit Stamp 2. I visited https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa and this sentence: "You must also have an Irish biometric visa (marked ‘BC’ or ‘BC BIVS’ in the ‘Remarks’ section)" made me unsure whether I am exempt from transit visa or not. Ireland abolished re-entry visa (http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/Re-entry+visas) so there is nothing in my Passport to confirm the remarks section as showing my Irish Residence Permit card would replace the Re-Entry visa

Is there anyone that can confirm whether I need/not need UK transit visa?

Comment: To improve clarity, I have edited the title and second paragraph of your question. If I have misunderstood your question or your itinerary, the text can be reverted to what you posted originally. But then I found something awry with the itinerary: Qantas QF1 flies between Singapore and London, not Sydney and London. Now I'm not sure which direction (Europe > Asia, or Asia > Europe) you're asking about. Please restate your complete itinerary, including all legs to be flown, stops made, and all airlines involved.

Comment: @David Thanks! I've added my itinerary details after the second paragraph

Comment: You will go through immigration in London, because of the Common Travel Area. Do you have any Irish visa in addition to the residence stamp?

Comment: @AndrewLazarus I have the initial student visa but I don't think it's valid anymore (26/08/16 to 25/11/16). I also have a re-entry visa from last year but i don't think it's valid either (02/02/18 to 30/09/18). Normally I would apply for re-entry visa as well for this trip, but Ireland abolished the re-entry visa and said that IRP would suffice as prove to enter the country, so I the only thing I have in my passport is Immigration Stamp when I get my IRP card (valid until 30/09/19)

Comment: Although there is no reason for governments to do what makes sense, one issue is whether your biometrics have been taken. Sounds like Yes. The second is whatever the special BC endorsement means, and for that, I have no idea.

Comment: Congrats, you found a very rare UK government page with [confusing](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/indonesia/transit/republic_of_ireland) information on it. As explained below, the IRP is actually sufficient to allow you to transit the UK landside, which you must do to go to Ireland. Airlines everywhere will recognize the IRP as it looks like every other EU common format residence permit.

Comment: @David QF1 flies Sydney-Singapore-London.

Comment: @MichaelHampton so even if i have to go through immigration in London, showing my IRP is sufficient enough?

Comment: @Indokid It's sufficient for everyone else who does it every day. It's a common question and [we've answered it before here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/139063/3221).

Answer (score 2):

According to Timatic, transiting UK without a visa is possible for:
nationals of Indonesia making a landside transit with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country that departs before 23:59 the next day. They must:

- have a common format residence permit issued by Ireland (Rep.), and
- clear immigration, and
- have documents required for the next destination.

https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external-result/olo-GnaVwj0nMAsfqkH40_cx3DUZ

Comment: @David [The IRP](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/139063/3221) is a common format residence permit. It looks like every other EU member state's permits. And strangely, that UK government page is wrong.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Thanks for the clarity; I wondered if the UK govt page was in error, but didn't search effectively. Your reference (above) to a previous question on the same topic makes my comments and apprehension unfounded. I'll delete my comment.

Comment: @David It's so rare to find an error on the UK government web site that your apprehension was entirely appropriate. IRP holders can transit without visa under V 7.8 (h) of the [immigration rules](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules) like any other EEA/Switzerland residence permit holder.