# Filipino citizens with Norwegian resident permits transiting at London Heathrow - Do We need a Transit Visa?

Tags: visas, transit, lhr, filipino-citizens, norway

We are gonna be four people travelling from Norway to the Philippines in December. Two of us are filipino citizens with valid Norwegian resident permits. Do we need a transit visa if we want to go landside? I am not sure if a Norwegian resident permit is considered "common format". All help is much appreciated.

Comment: As a general guide, a residence permit for an EU country does not allow the holder to enter the UK if they would otherwise need a visa by virtue of their citizenship, unless the permit is a valid Article 10 residence card and they are travelling with or visiting either their partner or a family member in the UK. https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/entering-the-uk-as-the-holder-of-an-article-10-residence-card/entering-the-uk-as-the-holder-of-an-article-10-residence-card

Comment: @Traveller: EEA common format residence permits do qualify the holder for landside transit-without-visa in the UK if certain other conditions are met.

Comment: Voting to reopen, because the OP is evidently aware of the TWOV rules, and is asking _specifically_ about how he finds out whether his Norwegian residence permit qualifies as a "common format" permit, which is not explained by the prior question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to find out if I need a transit visa for a layover in the UK?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34106/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-if-i-need-a-transit-visa-for-a-layover-in-the-uk)

Answer (score 1):

A common-format residence card is one issued by an EEA or EU country whose design matches the one shown [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/139063/16947). The most important features to look for is the red-blue-red background pattern, and stars and a bull symbol on the left-hand side above the photo. (The background pattern on the right is a national design that differs between member countries).

If you have such a card and satisfy certain other conditions (leaving by air before two midnights have passed etc.) then you should qualify for the landside Transit Without Visa scheme.